# is there a function in dlg class as getdocument()?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to get a `doc*` in `dlg` class, and i know in view class we can get `doc*` like

```
doc* pdc=getdocument();
```

But how can i do it in `dlg` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MFC's CDialog class does not have built-in CDocument's.  You can implement a CFormView that is derived from CView (which are part of the Document/View architecture of MFC), but CFormView is not a dialog.  However, CFormView's can hold controls like a dialog - you can actually assign a dialog template to a CFormView.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in `CDialog` to retrieve a document pointer. To give your dialog access to the document, you can add a pointer or reference to the document as a member variable of the dialog class, and initialise it in the dialog's constructor.

```
CMyDocument* doc = GetDocument();
CMyDialog dialog(doc);
dialog.DoModal();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get document from dialog by doing as follows:

```
CMainFrame* pFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();    
CMyProjDoc* pDoc = (CMyProjDoc*)(pFrame->GetActiveDocument());

pDoc->m_item[i].name  // use
```